# PDCurses mvprintw error with structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, curses, pdcurses

I'm using PDCurses and i want to show a list of films with it.

My code is this one :

```
typedef struct{
int     nId;                    /*  Id du film                      */
int     nId_Genre;              /*  Id du genre                     */
int     nId_Distributeur;       /*  Id du distributeur              */
char*   pszTitre;               /*  Titre du film                   */
char*   pszResume;              /*  Resumé du film                  */
char*   pszDate_Debut;          /*  Date de début du film           */
char*   pszDate_Fin;            /*  Date de fin du film             */
int     nDuree;                 /*  Durée du film                   */
int     nAnnee;                 /*  Année du film                   */
struct  FILMS_NEW* pNext;       /*  Pointeur sur le prochain film     */
}FILMS_NEW;

typedef FILMS_NEW * PFILMS_NEW;


int DisplayListFilms(){
PFILMS_NEW pFilm;
int nCount=0,nSizeString;
int i=9;
WINDOW *menu_win;
int startx = 0;
int starty = 0;

initscr();
start_color();          /* Start color functionality    */
clear();
noecho();
cbreak();   /* Line buffering disabled. pass on everything */
startx = (180 - WIDTH) / 2;
starty = (40 - HEIGHT) / 2;

init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
attron(A_BOLD);

mvprintw(1, startx+6, "*************************************\n");
mvprintw(2, startx+6, "****                           ******");
mvprintw(3, startx+6, "****      LISTE OF FILMS       ******");
mvprintw(4, startx+6, "****                           ******");
mvprintw(5, startx+6, "*************************************");
mvprintw(7, 0,ENTETE_F);
refresh();

if ((pFilm = pRootFilm) == NULL)
    return 0;


while (pFilm)
{
    mvprintw(i, 0, (char *)pFilm->nId);
    mvprintw(i, 5, (char *)pFilm->nId_Genre);
    mvprintw(i, 10, (char *)pFilm->nId_Distributeur);
    mvprintw(i, 15, pFilm->pszTitre);
    mvprintw(i, 20, pFilm->pszResume);
    mvprintw(i, 25, pFilm->pszDate_Debut);
    mvprintw(i, 30, pFilm->pszDate_Fin);
    mvprintw(i, 35, (char *)pFilm->nDuree);
    mvprintw(i, 40, (char *)pFilm->nAnnee);

    pFilm = pFilm->pNext;
    nCount++;
    i++;
}

return nCount;
```

}

Why is it not working? And why is it working if I put mvprintw(i,0,"toto")?

Pleeeease help !!!! I need to do it for next month :)

Comment: what is the definition of  `PFILMS_NEW`?

Comment: typedef struct
{
    int     nId;                    /*  Id du film                      */
(...)    
struct  FILMS_NEW* pNext;  
} FILMS_NEW;

typedef FILMS_NEW * PFILMS_NEW;

Comment: Please [edit your question and add the details there](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29944977/edit). in comments it's barely readable. Also, as a first look, do you need something like  `mvprintw(i, 0, (char *)&pFilm->nId);`, (notice the `&`)

Comment: I've changed
With & i have no error but I have no result on my screen

Comment: I think I got the problem. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like, your usage of `mvprintw()` is wrong. As per the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/mvprintw.html), the synax is

```
int mvprintw(int y, int x, char *fmt, ...);
```

so, you need to write your code like

```
mvprintw(i, 0, "%d", pFilm->nId);  //for ints
.
.
mvprintw(i, 15, "%s", pFilm->pszTitre); // for strings
```

Comment: same as `mvprintw(i, 0, (char *)&pFilm->nId);`

Comment: @Gwenvael No, it's not the same, at all. You can't just take a pointer to an int, cast it as a pointer to a char, and expect that to print. You'll get gibberish, if you're lucky.

Comment: Sorry when i say its same, i mean its the same result : nothing on screen :)